# transform Method is not getting call in MAIN method?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.cluster;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring.BetweennessCentrality;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.Pair;

    public class EdgeBetweennessClusterer<V, E> implements
        Transformer<Graph<V, E>, Set<Set<V>>> {
    private int mNumEdgesToRemove;
    private Map<E, Pair<V>> edges_removed;


    public EdgeBetweennessClusterer(int numEdgesToRemove) {
        mNumEdgesToRemove = numEdgesToRemove;
        edges_removed = new LinkedHashMap<E, Pair<V>>();


    }
      public Set<Set<V>> transform(Graph<V, E> graph) {

        if (mNumEdgesToRemove < 0
                || mNumEdgesToRemove > graph.getEdgeCount()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid number of edges passed in.");
        }

        edges_removed.clear();

        for (int k = 0; k < mNumEdgesToRemove; k++) {
            BetweennessCentrality<V, E> bc = new BetweennessCentrality<V, E>(
                    graph);
            E to_remove = null;
            double score = 0;
            for (E e : graph.getEdges())
                if (bc.getEdgeScore(e) > score) {
                    to_remove = e;
                    score = bc.getEdgeScore(e);
                }
            edges_removed.put(to_remove, graph.getEndpoints(to_remove));
            graph.removeEdge(to_remove);
        }

        WeakComponentClusterer<V, E> wcSearch = new WeakComponentClusterer<V, E>();
        Set<Set<V>> clusterSet = wcSearch.transform(graph);

        for (Map.Entry<E, Pair<V>> entry : edges_removed.entrySet()) {
            Pair<V> endpoints = entry.getValue();
            graph.addEdge(entry.getKey(), endpoints.getFirst(),
                    endpoints.getSecond());
        }
        Object array[];
        array=new Object[500];
        array=clusterSet.toArray();
        System.out.println(array.length);
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)

        {
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("hkj"+array[i]);
        }
        return clusterSet;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the list of all edges that were removed
     * (assuming extract(...) was previously called). 
     * The edges returned
     * are stored in order in which they were removed.
     *
     * @return the edges in the original graph
     */
    public List<E> getEdgesRemoved() {
        return new ArrayList<E>(edges_removed.keySet());
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new EdgeBetweennessClusterer(10);
    }
}
```

This algorithm is copied from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Science/jung-2-2_0_1/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/EdgeBetweennessClusterer.java.htm)

I am making network based community so I used this algorithm 
when I am running this code, the main method, and is not getting called.  I am not able to understand what is happening.  Correct me if I am wrong. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove all the code which doesn't do anything your program is the same as

```
public EdgeBetweennessClusterer(int numEdgesToRemove) {
    mNumEdgesToRemove = numEdgesToRemove;
    edges_removed = new LinkedHashMap<E, Pair<V>>();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new EdgeBetweennessClusterer(10);
}
```

If you want your program to call more code, you need to tell it to do so.  Perhaps using a debugger will help you see what your program is doing any why.

Answer (score 1):

transform isn't being called because you're not calling it. Try the following:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new EdgeBetweennessClusterer(10).transform(graph);
}
```

You can fill in your value for graph.

Comment: "Not being called because you are not calling it." Well said, short and slightly sarcastic!

Comment: @ Matthew Its saying graph variable is not declared

Comment: @Adams That's because you have probably misunderstood the purpose of the EdgeBetweennessClusterer. The class needs a Graph object as inputs, and will cluster that graph into different clusters. You need to construct a graph before using the clusterer for anything useful. I would suggest that you start by reading an introduction to java book or the sun java tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. Attempting to start using the clusterer without ever having programmed before is kind of like trying to calculate integrals and derivatives without having learnt basic arithmetics before.

Answer (score 0):

It is not being called because you are not calling it.

In your main method, try keeping a hold to an instance of your `EdgeBetweennessClusterer` and invoke `transform()` on it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Graph graph = buildGraph();
    EdgeBetweennessClusterer clusterer = new EdgeBetweennessClusterer(10);
    Set mySet = clusterer.transform(graph);
}
```

I left out the generics being I do not know what types you are wanting to deal with...

Comment: This error is coming `cannot find
symbol
method
buildGraph()`

Comment: Well, you have to provide an implementation for it to build a `Graph` object, because that is what your `transform(Graph)` method takes as a parameter.

Comment: i know this is really silly can u tell me code . i am not getting that  how i build `graph` object

Comment: Well, you should take a look at the documentation provided by the developers of the code you are using.  I found this (hyperlink at end of comment) for the graph, but you will have to do it yourself, as I do not know anything about the type of `Graph` you are working with.  http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Graph.html

Comment: i think in graph.Java file they have made many graph they are taking from there and transforming into graph  . can i do this in main any help

Comment: nicholas . if there is something in short which will help me out

Comment: There isn't something 'in short'.  You probably should become more familiar with programming before you just ask for a solution.  Take a look at some reading is my only advice -- http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not calling the method. If you want it to be called upon construction, place a call to `transform()` in constructor of your object